# Type hinting pandas dataframe with specific columns/vectors

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, type-hinting

i have a function likes this:

```
def func(y, predicted_y, sample_weights: pd.core.series.Series) -> float:
    result = y / (predicted_y + y)

    return (result * sample_weights).sum() / sample_weights.sum()
```

where `y`, `predicted_y` are vectors - the actual target column of my dataframe and the predicted target column of my dataframe.

How to specify the type hint for them? I used `pd.core.series.Series` for `sample_weights` is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain but could this help?

```
from typing import Union
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def func(y: Union[np.ndarray, pd.Series], 
         predicted_y: Union[np.ndarray, pd.Series], 
         sample_weights: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    
    result = y / (predicted_y + y)
    return result * sample_weights
```

Comment: thanks, i updated the output of this function, i think the type of the output should be a float right? a follow-up question if that's ok, why we need `Union[np.ndarray, pd.Series]`? why can't we also just use `pd.Series`?

Comment: @wawawa
Using Union[np.ndarray, pd.Series] as the type hint for the y and predicted_y arguments allows the function to accept both NumPy arrays and pandas Series as inputs. This is useful because sometimes data is stored as NumPy arrays and sometimes as pandas Series. By allowing both types of inputs, the function becomes more flexible and can be used with a wider range of data.
If you are to use pd.Series instead of Union[np.ndarray, pd.Series], the function would only accept pandas Series as input, and not NumPy arrays.

Comment: makes sense, thanks, if the function returns `return (result * sample_weights).sum() / sample_weights.sum()` then the type hinting should be a `float` right?

Comment: @wawawa That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd

def func(y: pd.Series,
         predicted_y: pd.Series,
         sample_weights: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:

    result = y / (predicted_y + y)
    return result * sample_weights
```

Output:

```
>>> help(func)
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(y: pandas.core.series.Series, predicted_y: pandas.core.series.Series, sample_weights: pandas.core.series.Series) -> pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: why can't we just use pd.Series for `y` and `predicted_y`?

Comment: @wawawa. I updated my answer can you check it please? The output is a Series too